# Understanding function scopes when it comes to mutables

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

For some reasons, Python is able to access mutables in the scope of an inner function if the mutable is modified in-place (or is not modified at all).

The same does not apply to immutables, unless they are declared as `nonlocal`, see `f7` and `f8`.

Modifying a mutable with any operator that does not modify the variale in-place causes an `UnboundLocalError` exception.

However, I could not find anything specific to this behaviour in the Python docs (or I was unable to identify this information).

What I've been looking at:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces
https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names

And what somehow made sense to me was:

> When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the nearest enclosing scope. The set of all such scopes visible to a code block is called the block’s environment.
>   [...]
>
> If a name binding operation occurs anywhere within a code block, all uses of the name within the block are treated as references to the current block. This can lead to errors when a name is used within a block before it is bound. This rule is subtle. Python lacks declarations and allows name binding operations to occur anywhere within a code block. The local variables of a code block can be determined by scanning the entire text of the block for name binding operations.

I think this explains why `f1` and `f3` work, while `f2` and `f4` don't, however, I'm still confused as to why `f6` does not work - after all the use of `c[0] = c[0]` happens before `c = c`.

**So my question is:**

Why does `f6` not work? Is the later use of `c = c` somehow "shadowing" the outer scope?

If it is, where is this behaviour described in the docs?

I would really appreciate if you could back up your answer with a reference to an official documentation of the behaviour.

Here are some functions to reproduce my findings:

```
import inspect

def f1():
    c = [0]
    def g():
        print(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_freevars) # ('c',)
        c[0] = c[0]
        return c
    return g
f1()()

def f2():
    c = [0]
    def g():
        print(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_freevars) # ()
        c = c # UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment
        return c
    return g
# f2()()

def f3():
    c = [0]
    def g():
        print(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_freevars) # ('c',)
        c.append(1)
        return c
    return g
f3()()

def f4():
    c = [0]
    def g():
        print(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_freevars) # ()
        c = c[0] # UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment
        return c
    return g
# f4()()

def f5():
    c = [0]
    def g():
        nonlocal c
        print(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_freevars) # ('c',)
        c = c
        return c
    return g
f5()()

def f6():
    c = [0]
    def g():
        print(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_freevars) # ()
        c[0] = c[0] # UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment
        c = c
        return c
    return g
f6()()

def f7():
    c = 1
    def g():
        print(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_freevars) # ()
        c = c # UnboundLocalError: local variable 'c' referenced before assignment
        return c
    return g
# f7()()

def f8():
    c = 1
    def g():
        nonlocal c
        print(inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_freevars) # ('c',)
        c = c
        return c
    return g
f8()()
```

Comment: *"Is the later use of c = c somehow "shadowing" the outer scope?"* pretty much yes, from what I remember. Just woke up so I can't go searching for docs (which I'm pretty sure don't mention something on this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have ignored a part of the documentation you quoted. Here is is with added emphasis:

> If a name binding operation occurs **anywhere within a code block**, all uses of the name within the block are treated as references to the current block.

In your example, the "code block" is the inner function and the "name binding operation" is the `c = c` assignment. It doesn't matter that the assignment is a no-op. When you do an assignment to the name `c` anywhere in the function (regardless of what value is assigned), the compiler will note that `c` is a local variable and so *all* uses of `c` (even those that occur earlier) will be treated as local references.